# How to check if list is empty inside a vue.js template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Pretty simple question.

In my vue.js template I have:

```
<template v-for="node in nodes">
  [[ node ]]
</template>
```

I want to return nodes in the list or print "N/A" if the list is empty.

I know how to do this with a js function, but not sure how to accomplish the same thing from within the template.

Comment: you mean you want to check if nodes list is empty ?

Answer (score 11):

You should check for both `undefined` and `length` using `Vue's` `v-if`.  If you ever use `asyncComputed` for example, it will be `undefined` until the async method resolves.  So you are covered for `nodes=null`, `nodes=undefined`, and `nodes=[]`.

```html
<template v-if="!nodes">
  Loading
</template>
<template v-else-if="!nodes.length">
  Empty
</template>
<template v-else v-for="node in nodes">
  {{ node }}
</template>
```

Or combine them

```html
<template v-if="!nodes || !nodes.length">
  Nothing To Show
</template>
<template v-else v-for="node in nodes">
  {{ node }}
</template>
```

I like using `!nodes.length` instead of `length !== 0` just in case something unexpected besides an array ends up in the data, in which case it will most likely use the `empty` template and not throw an exception. Less typing too!

Answer (score 3):

You can check like:

```
<template v-if="nodes.length">  // When there are some records available in nodes
  // Iterate it and display the data
</template >
<template v-else>
  // No record found
</template>
```

[Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

Answer (score 0):

to check if a list is empty, you just need to use `v-if`,  in that way your template will be like below :

```
<template v-if="nodes.length === 0">
  N/A
</template>

<template v-for="node in nodes"  v-else>
  [[ node ]]
</template>
```

for more information about [Conditional Rendering
VueJs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) please check the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Use render function like

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      nodes: ['item 1', 'item 2']
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    if (this.nodes.length == 0) {
      return h('p', 'No item')
    } else {
      return h(
        'p',
        {},
        this.nodes.map((item) => h('p', item))
      )
    }
  }
}
```